# How to update yiiactiveform settings when form is dynamically modified by js?

Tags: javascript, yii

I've form generated by CActiveForm, but when i put to form next ones inputs by javascript validation not affects on these.

I know properties for all assigned inputs is available on `$('ourForm').data('settings').attributes`.

I will have done solution by editing attributes, but I wondering whether it is other simplest way to done that?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same, and this is what I'm come up with:

```
var settings = $('#my-active-form').data('settings');
    settings.attributes.push({
        enableAjaxValidation: true,
        errorCssClass: "has-error",
        errorID: 'InputId_em_',
        id: 'InputId',
        inputContainer: "div.form-group",
        model: 'ModelName',
        name: 'modelName[attribute]',
        status: 1,
        successCssClass: 'has-success',
        validateOnChange: true
        //... some other params here...
    });

    jQuery('#my-active-form').yiiactiveform(settings);
```

Works fine. note that inputContainer, errorCssClass, successCssClass and attributes like that are dependent to style you are using to display your active form fields. This are settings for bootstrap 3 styled active form inputs